# How can I add code into my directive with transclude and pass in a parameter in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have code like the following that's used in many places in my application and
would like to replace some of this HTML with a directive. I realize there is 
not so much I can replace as the HTML's are so different:

```
<div class="select-area">
   <span>Subject</span>
   <select data-ng-disabled="option.subjects.length == 0"
           data-ng-model="option.selectedSubject"
           data-ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in option.subjects">
   </select>
</div>

<div class="select-area" data-ng-hide="utilityService.isNotNumber(option.selectedTopic)">
   <span>Subtopic</span>
   <select data-ng-model="option.selectedSubtopic"
           data-ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in option.subtopicsPlus">
   </select>
</div>
```

I would like to use a directive but I am not really sure how to start. I want to use
transclude to replace the inside  so I was thinking that my directive call 
would look something like this:

```
<div class="select-area" my-select-area="Subject">
   <select data-ng-disabled="option.subjects.length == 0"
           data-ng-model="option.selectedSubject"
           data-ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in option.subjects">
   </select>
</div>

<div class="select-area" data-ng-hide="utilityService.isNotNumber(option.selectedTopic)" my-select-area="Subtopic">
   <select data-ng-model="option.selectedSubtopic"
           data-ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in option.subtopicsPlus">
   </select>
</div>
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
app.directive('mySelect', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        template: "<div class='select-area'>" +
                  "<span> </span>" +

                  "</div>",
    };
});
```

Can someone show me how I can pass in the parameter that goes inside the span and also how I can add transclude?

**Update**: Based on Bastien's answer

There were a couple of small syntax errors but based on Bastien's answer I tried the following:

```
app.directive('mySelect', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div class='select-area'>" +
                    "<span> {{ mySelectArea }} </span>" +
                    "<div ng-transclude></div>" +
                  "</div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.mySelectArea = attrs.mySelectArea;
        }
    }
});
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div data-my-select myselectarea="Page type">
   <select data-ng-model="option.selectedPageType"
           data-ng-options="item.id as item.type for item in option.pageTypes"></select>
</div>
```

Here's the HTML it created:

```
<div data-my-select="" myselectarea="Page type">
<div class="select-area">
   <span class="ng-binding">  </span>
   <div ng-transclude="">
   <select data-ng-model="option.selectedPageType" 
           data-ng-options="item.id as item.type for item in option.pageTypes" 
           class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid">
      <option value="0">Edit Basic</option>
      <option value="1" selected="selected">Edit Standard</option>
      <option value="2">Report</option>
   </select>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

What I really need is for it to create this:

```
<div class="select-area">
   <span>Page Type</span>
   <select data-ng-model="option.selectedPageType" 
           data-ng-options="item.id as item.type for item in option.pageTypes" 
           class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
      <option value="0">Edit Basic</option>
      <option value="1" selected="selected">Edit Standard</option>
      <option value="2">Report</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I recommend you reading the official docs on directive and i think it will surely resolve your problem still if you have some doubt you can again put a question http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your current solution? The one extra `<div ng-transclude>`? You can add `replace=true` to your directive to get rid off wrapper div and then you actually have what you want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

About transclusion, I advise you to take a look to [this section of the doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives_demo_creating-a-directive-that-wraps-other-elements). In your case, you have to:

1. ask for transclusion in the directive definition object
2. indicate in the template which element will receive the transcluded elements with the *ng-transclude* directive

That give us this directive:

```
app.directive('mySelect', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div class='select-area'>" +
                    "<span> </span>" +
                    "<div ng-transclude></div>" +
                  "</div>"
    };
});
```

About passing a parameter, you have access to the attributes of the directive on the third parameter of the [link](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives_demo_creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom) function:

```
app.directive('mySelect', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div class='select-area'>" +
                    "<span> </span>" +
                    "<div ng-transclude></div>" +
                  "</div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        }
    };
});
```

Then, if your parameter is **always** plain text you can access the value directly:

```
attrs.mySelectArea
```

Otherwise, if your parameter can be in the scope you can use the [$parse](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24parse) service to get its value:

```
$parse(attrs.mySelectArea)(scope)
```

To display the value in the template, you have to provide it in the scope:

```
app.directive('mySelect', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div class='select-area'>" +
                    "<span> {{ mySelectArea }} </span>" +
                    "<div ng-transclude></div>" +
                  "</div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.mySelectArea = attrs.mySelectArea;
        }
    };
```

Finally, if you want that your directive template replace the element you can use the replace option ([more infos](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile#description_comprehensive-directive-api)):

```
app.directive('mySelect', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: "<div class='select-area'>" +
                    "<span> {{ mySelectArea }} </span>" +
                    "<div ng-transclude></div>" +
                  "</div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.mySelectArea = attrs.mySelectArea;
        }
    };
```

I made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XSgofZ8cPGasXsiRaBw4?p=preview) of it.

I strongly advise you to to deep dive into the [directive guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and the [directive API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile#description_comprehensive-directive-api) to have a good sight of what can be done with directives.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out and then accept or ask you for a bit more help if I have a problem.

Comment: Feel free to ask for more info

Comment: I tried it out but it's not quite what I expected. I think something small is not quite right. I updated the question with what I see. Hope you can have some ideas what might be the problem. Also would it be possible to call the directive like this: <div data-my-select="Subject">  By the way sorry but I may not be able to retest this for a while as it's 1:30am now in my timezone. thanks I will check tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `<div ng-transclude>` directive will always result in a wrapping `<div>` in your rendered html. There are other ways to include the transcluded content programatically. For example, your link function gets passed a transclude function as the last argument. That function takes a callback that lets you attach the transcluded content wherever you like:

```
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
        scope.mySelectArea = attrs.mySelectArea;
        transclude(function(dom){
          element.append(dom);
        });
    }
```

I've updated the plunkr from the other option using this technique:

http://plnkr.co/edit/sFL9uVt4mx60NtZq41yE?p=preview